# Matrix with infinity on main diagonal

Tags: matrix, syntax

The question is trivial, however, there might be unexpected solutions. What would be nice way to create a square matrix with $\infty$ on main diagonal, and some arbitrary constant everywhere else?

My first thought was to do something like this:

```
\[Infinity] * IdentityMatrix[t] + ConstantArray[1, {t,t}] (*this is not working!*)
```

However, it's not working because $0*\infty$ is indeterminate. `DiagonalMatrix` is not working with infinite entries

```
DiagonalMatrix@ConstantArray[\[Infinity], t] (*not working either!*)
```

Trivial solution works, but its ugly:

```
Table[If[a == b, \[Infinity], 1], {a, Range[t]}, {b, Range[t]}]
```

More interesting and even a bit more performance effective is following code:

```
SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> \[Infinity], {t, t}] + ConstantArray[1, {t, t}]
```

But I still have the feeling that it could be done way better.

Comment: @Alexander  In your third solution, you can replace `{a, Range[t]}` with `{a,t}` in two places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> Infinity, {3, 3}, 2] // Normal
```

Creates a 3×3 with 2 everywhere but the diagonal of infinity. Drop the `// Normal` if you want to keep it sparse...

Comment: Could've also been done as `SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> ∞, {3, 3}, 2]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.: Yes. `Band` faster for this though... at least in a quick few tests.

Comment: Oh, they've improved `Band[]`? Last time I used it, it was the other way around; good to know it's better in the current version.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.: Not sure about that - it's faster for this simple case, I *think* the perf. issue was with multiple bands specified... might test at some point myself.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
Infinity*IdentityMatrix[5] //. Indeterminate -> q // Quiet
```

This creates a 5 by 5 matrix with all values equal to `q` except along the diagonal where the value is infinity.

Comment: You don't need `ReplaceRepeated`, simple `ReplaceAll` will do, and this will be quite slow for large instances...